# My use of __str__() inside of another object's __str__() is not working

Tags: string, object, implementation, using

I'm trying to use **str** to create a string representation of my object and use is when printing another object that uses this object.  My implementation isn't working though.

I saw this: [How to properly define a return string within a for loop for a Class using OOP in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650679/how-to-properly-define-a-return-string-within-a-for-loop-for-a-class-using-oop-i)
and thought I had everything correct, but I'm still not getting what I want in the output

Here is my code:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        print("using Card.__str__()")
        return self.name

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []

    def add_cards(self, cds):
        self.deck.append(cds)

    def __str__(self):
        print("using Deck.__str__()")
        temp = ""
        for i in range(len(self.deck)): # <- iterating over list of Card objs
            temp += str(self.deck[i])  # <- deck[i] is Card obj, why doesn't this use Card.__str__()?
            if i < len(self.deck)-1:
                temp += ", "
        return temp

card1 = Card("Apples")
card2 = Card("Peaches")
card3 = Card("Grapes")
card4 = Card("Pears")
cards = [card1, card2, card3, card4]
deck = Deck()
deck.add_cards(cards)
print(deck)
```

I'm expecting to see:

Apples, Peaches, Grapes, Pears

But instead I'm getting:

using deck.**str**()
[<**main**.Card object at 0x7f7f1d1103a0>, <**main**.Card object at 0x7f7f1d146520>, <**main**.Card object at 0x7f7f1d1
46be0>, <**main**.Card object at 0x7f7f1d146dc0>]

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Your `Deck`'s `deck` list contains a single element - a list of four `Card`s.  (And the `str()` of a list is built from the `repr()` of its elements, rather than their `str()`).  `.add_cards()` should probably use `.extend()`, rather than `.append()`.